# Copy/rename google sheet, share & get share id with script in form

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible for a script to copy/rename an (unrelated) Google spreadsheet, share it with a given email (preferably testing for the existence of a google account associated with the given email first), and save the shared url? I have spent hours and can't find any part of the answer to this: nothing on copying/renaming, nothing on share id. I may be missing some keyword or something. I realize I'll probably be downvoted for a general question, but this is the only Google Script support out there, I think. If you give me a thread, I'll follow it.

Comment: I don't really get why I was downvoted for this. I asked a as-specific-as-I-could-figure-out-to-be question, I had done hours of research beforehand -- maybe I still seemed clueless, but... what exactly is a forum for? If no one wants to answer, fine, but to downvote without any indication why seems unfortunate. I finally figured it out, with help, and it was non-trivial (by my standards: see below). Was it an ill-asked question, or something else? I would think downvoting ought to require comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So: I had to figure this out, and finally hired someone to code this snippet for me, here's what I got. This works pretty great for me. I did a tiny bit of customization.

Here's the requirement:
Given 2 Google Sheets, GTemplate & GTracker (these are two separate spreadsheets, not tabs in the same spreadsheet). Create a form (that reports to a tab/sheet in GTracker) which a user (anyone) fills in online with an email "UserEmail", and a string "UserID". Upon submission:
1) Make a copy of GTemplate, and rename it to "GTUserID" (if GTUserID already exists, name it GTUserID1, 2, or whatever)
2) Check that the submitted email has an associated Google Account
3) Share GTUserID with UserEmail
4) Save the URL of GTUserID to GTracker
5) Send an email to UserEmail confirming success or failure of above

```
    //************ Edit here *******************************

    var stremplateID = '1PBO9KhoZa9iX3Uik-FxXGnvhgs0BoNQUJmV95UUg56o';

    //******************************************************



function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Initialization')
      .addItem('Initialize', 'setTrigger')
      .addToUi();
}


function setTrigger(){

var arr=   ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

for (var i= arr.length; i>0; i--){
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(arr[i-1])
}


 ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
          .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp
          .getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())
          .onFormSubmit()
          .create()
}




function onFormSubmit(e) {

    try {

        //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

        var folder;
        var strEmail = e.namedValues.Email;
        var strUID = e.namedValues['User ID'];
        //Logger.log(strEmail)
        //Logger.log(strUID)

        var oldFile = DriveApp.getFileById(stremplateID);
        var folders = oldFile.getParents();
        while (folders.hasNext()) {
                folder = folders.next();
                break;
        }

            if ((typeof folder) != "object") {
                folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
            }

            var bolFlag = false;
            var bolFlag1 = false;
            var i = 0;

            var myRegexp = new RegExp('[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]','g');
            var strProcUID=String(strUID).replace(myRegexp, "_");
            //Logger.log(strProcUID)

            var strFilename = strProcUID;
            while (!bolFlag) {
                var files = folder.getFiles();
                while (files.hasNext()) {
                    var file = files.next();
                    if (file.getName() == strFilename) {
                        bolFlag1 = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!bolFlag1) {
                    bolFlag = true;
                } else {
                    i = i + 1;
                    strFilename = strProcUID + i;
                    bolFlag1 = false;
                }
            }

            var newFile = oldFile.makeCopy(strFilename, folder);
            newFile.addEditors(strEmail);

            var link = newFile.getUrl();

        var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
        var row = sh.getLastRow();
        var col = sh.getLastColumn();

        sh.getRange(row, col, 1, 1).setValue(link);

        var body = 'Dear ' + strUID + ',\n' +
            'Your request has been processed successfully.\n' +
            'The file can be seen here:\n' +
            link + '\n' +
            'Regards,\n ' +
            'Admin';

            GmailApp.sendEmail(strEmail, 'Request Processed', body);

    } catch (e) {

        var body = '\n' +
            'An error occurred while processing the request:\n' +
            'User ID: ' + strUID + '\n ' +
            'Email: ' + strEmail + '\n ' +
            'Error: ' + e;

            GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), 'Error processing a request', body);

            var body = 'Dear ' + strUID + ',\n' +
            'Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.\n' +
            'Regards,\n ' +
            'Admin';

            GmailApp.sendEmail(strEmail, 'Error processing the request', body);

    }
}
```

Perhaps this will be helpful to someone else. The things it does that I couldn't find was copying a copied/shared Google Sheet URL into a different sheet (for creating daughter shared documents for different projects, initiated by the project teams, still owned by the admin account, with internal fields readily accessible since we've got the URL). I hope that's clear and helpful.